# scatter plots in seaborn/matplotlib with point size and color given by continuous dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to make a scatter plot in seaborn/matplotlib where the size of points is determined by a (continuous) value in a dataframe, and the color of points is also determined by the continuous value of another column in dataframe. In ggplot, the way to do it is:

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, size=Petal.Width, color=Petal.Length))
```

[image]
(color/size here are continuous not categorical values)

what's the syntax for this in seaborn/matplotlib?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following reproduces the code diagram from the question. 
Optaining a legend is a bit cumbersome, because we have to manually define some proxy artists to put to the legend and remove the first automatic legend entry which is generated via the seaborn style.

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

plt.scatter(iris.sepal_width, iris.sepal_length, 
            c = iris.petal_length, s=(iris.petal_width**2)*60, cmap="viridis")
ax = plt.gca()

plt.colorbar(label="petal_length")
plt.xlabel("sepal_width")
plt.ylabel("sepal_length")

#make a legend:
pws = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2., 2.5]
for pw in pws:
    plt.scatter([], [], s=(pw**2)*60, c="k",label=str(pw))

h, l = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(h[1:], l[1:], labelspacing=1.2, title="petal_width", borderpad=1, 
            frameon=True, framealpha=0.6, edgecolor="k", facecolor="w")

plt.show()
```

Note that the  size argument `s` denotes the area of the dots. So in order to have the diameter be proportional to the quantitiy to show, it has to to be squared.

Comment: thanks. ggplot maps continuous quantity to discrete legend with bins. is there no way to do this in matplotlib? also the plots look very different, is it because matplotlib has weird default settings for marker sizes?

Comment: It's possible, but one has to do a lot by hand. See updated answer. The markersize looks different because I set it differently. As stated in the answer, I squared the values such that the markers' diameter is proportional to the quantity shown. Of course you may set any other size using the `s` argument.

Comment: is there a library in py that makes this easier? it's a lot of complex code. does seaborn make it possible?

Comment: Seaborn does not have this kind of legend out of the box. Most of the time, using seaborn makes things more complicated than pure matplotlib (I actually only imported it here to get the iris dataset and without it we could get rid of this legend_handles_labels stuff). That said, I am not aware of other libraries that provide this feature, but I'm also not an expert for plotly, bokeh, vispy or whatever other tools there are around.

Comment: @jll : See my answer below of solving this in few lines using Altair.

Comment: I would recommend adding bbox_to_anchor = (2,1), borderaxespad = 0.) to plt.legend() to push the legend outside of the plot.

Comment: `bbox_to_anchor = (2,1)` would put the legend outside the figure. So I would not recommend doing that. Solutions for putting the legend out of the plot are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132).

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would solve this using [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html)

```
from altair import Chart
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
c = Chart(iris)
c.mark_circle().encode(
    x='sepal_width',
    y='sepal_length',
    color='petal_length',
    size='petal_width',
)
```

[image]

For such plots, Altair might be a great choice. Quoting from their website:

> Altair is a declarative statistical visualization library for Python, based on Vega-Lite. With Altair, you can spend more time understanding your data and its meaning.