# What kind of Clustering plot is this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm in interview process with some company.

Task is, to see if there is any relationship between wealth-age and initial funded amount.

As a task, I'm developing a K-Means clustering algorithm, to get a brief idea about data here is the screenshot

[image]

I've created the k-means model, problem is with the task they also sent some data visualization example

[image]

I don't know how to plot something like this, I even don't like what kind of plot is this...

How can I use my K-means model prediction to plot something like this?

Comment: It is a simple scatter plot with marker size reflecting a third variable. [See here for a good explanation of how to scale the marker size.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403507/8881141) Not sure what the color represents in your plot, though.

Comment: Seaborn provides a way to directly use a variable to determine the size but makes other things more difficult in return: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42759867/8881141

Comment: Please include a link to the dataset in your question if on kaggle.

Comment: @DavidErickson Sure here is , https://www.kaggle.com/rutkaykarabulak/notebook589fe5c855 , I've developed my k-means algorithm but when I try to plot it I failed... I wish you cold help me

Comment: @RutkayKarabulak from your kaggle, can you please include either the output of your `y_kmeans` dataframe? Plotting can be pretty specific to the actual data, so I can't really help without the actual data.